# How to determine the shell that sources my script

Tags: bash, zsh

I am writing a script which might be sourced either by `bash` or `zsh`. Depending on the shell, my script might do things differently. Currently I have:

```sh
if [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]
then
    # Do the bash-specific stuff
elif [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]]
then
    # Do the zsh-specific stuff
fi
```

Question: Is there a different/better way to detect which shell is sourcing my script? I know about the `$SHELL` variable, but that is the default shell, not the shell that is sourcing my script.

Comment: I would recommend against trying to write a dual-shell script. Keep in mind that the entire `if` statement must parse successfully, regardless of which branch will be taken, so there can be cases where you can't simply "hide" `zsh`-only syntax from `bash`.

Comment: @chepner, I appreciate your input, but don't want to maintain two separate scripts because most of the code is the same for both shells.

Comment: Can you abstract the differing code into a file to source?

Comment: @HaiVu : I think your approach is kind of OK, at least if you have control of the environment. Of course, a (malevolent) user of some non-bash shell might legally set the variable `BASH_VERSION` before sourcing your, and trick your script into believing that it is executed by bash.

Comment: @chepner Your approach is probably what I will adopt: common code in one file, and depending on the shell, the common code will source different file. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no fundamentally better way.

However, you may wish to use POSIX compliant comparisons and `eval` any code that isn't valid POSIX:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
  eval 'declare -A foo=([shell]=bash)' 
elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]
then
  eval 'declare -A foo=([shell]=zsh)'
elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]
  eval 'declare -A foo=([shell]=ksh)'
else
  foo_shell="sh"
fi
```

This allows the script to work correctly under shells like `dash` which doesn't understand `[[ .. ]]`, and where array syntax would cause parsing errors.